# Programatically fetching Singleton instances that implement a common interface

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, singleton

I'm working with some legacy ASP.NET MVC code that has a number of fairly detailed XML configuration files. Each file is loaded into an object representation defined as a Singleton class at runtime.

Rather than having to refer to each singleton specifically by class type I'd like a way of obtaining each of them programatically and then being able to access properties and methods common to them all based on an interface which they must all implement.

So for example, these singletons all have a string instance property called "Filename" that is the name of the config file they represent. I'd therefore like to automatically generate a list of these filenames without manually having to refer to each singleton to obtain the property and therefore I need to programatically fetch all singleton instances implementing the interface that specifies the Filename property and then fetch that property value by casting to that interface.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you provide the layout of your singleton classes?

Comment: They're pretty weighty and would take up too much space to post in full, but essentially they're just your typical singleton implementation each of their own specific class type and not inheriting from anything, but implementing a common interface that just exposes a handful of public instance properties and methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned a simple singleton layout so i used this to test:

```
public interface IConfig { }

public class Config1 : IConfig
{
    public static Config1 Config = new Config1();

    private Config1()
    {
        FileName = "file.xml";
    }

    public string FileName { get; private set; }
}
```

To get all filenames you can use this bunch of linq:

```
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
    .Where(x => typeof (IConfig).IsAssignableFrom(x) && !x.IsAbstract)
    .ToList();

var objects = types.Select(x => x.GetFields().Single(y => x == y.FieldType).GetValue(null))
    .ToList();

var fileNames = objects.Select(x => x.GetType().GetProperty("FileName").GetValue(x)).ToList();
```

Maybe you have to change the assembly/s to search according your needs.

Comment: Cheers, I ended up realising I'd tried something similar and the reason it hadn't worked was because I was doing it somewhere that was called during instantiation of one of the configs hence creating a stack overflow leading me to wrongly believe earlier there was something wrong with a similar approach!